# Version management in Maven

Tags: maven-3, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have two different projects. Project_1 is a maven multi-module project. Project_2 depends on some modules of the Project_2. I have declared a version property in parent POM of Project_1 and referred in the child POM like below.

Project_1 Parent POM

```
<groupid>x</groupid>
<artifactid>y</artifactid>
<version>${app.version}</version>
<properties>
    <app.version>1.0.0</app.version>
</properties>
```

Project_1 Child POM

```
<parent>
    <groupid>x</groupid>
    <artifactid>y</artifactid>
    <version>${app.version}</version>
</parent>
<artifactid>y1</artifactid>
```

Project_2 POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupid>x</groupid>
    <artifactid>y</artifactid>
    <groupid>1.0.0</groupid>
</dependency>
```

I have installed Project_1 using "mvn clean install" in the local repository but the problem is Project_1 and its module pom and its dependencies installed in the local repo is with version ${app.version}. Due to this, If I refer the Project_1 or its modules as a dependency in Project_2 with the actual version 1.0.0, its throwing error that it can't find version 1.0.0

Is there any way to solve this? during install of Project_1, I like to override the key {app.version} with actual in the local repo.

Comment: I would not set the version with a property. Just set it in the `<version></version>` tag and use http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/usage.html to manage the version while building your project.
Also there seems to be a type in your Project_2 POM code example: `<groupid>` is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The same can be achieved by flatten-maven-plugin.
In case of Parent version include, flatten-maven-plugin can be used with xml-maven-plugin.